# How to set-up trigger only to Homepage - google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

how I can set-up trigger to fire only on Homepage? We´re using also UTM parameters so condition URL Path equals http://website.com is not working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a JavaScript variable in Google Tag Manager to return the value of `document.location.pathname`

This variable will contain the value of the current URL path, without any URL parameters or fragments.

You can then set your homepage trigger to fire when the value of your JavaScript variable equals `/`

Answer (score 0):

Pattern for a homepage  usually would be ^/$. In human language it means “starts and immediately ends with /”.

As URL variable contains domain name and possible query parameters (that is what goes after ?), better to use Page Path (Make sure you have it enabled in your GTM Account, under Variables > Enabled Built-In Variables).

http://www.apasters.com/blog/regex-guide-google-analytics-tag-manager/